# Project Euler #12 runs very slowly

Tags: python, programming-challenge, python-3.x, time-limit-exceeded

The problem is :

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>
> 3: 1,3
>
> 6: 1,2,3,6
>
> 10: 1,2,5,10
>
> 15: 1,3,5,15
>
> 21: 1,3,7,21
>
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

The code works now, when I set the condition in the last loop to 60, etc. instead of 500. But 500 is too big for it and it takes forever to answer (actually I didn't have enough patience to see how much time it takes, it takes a bit too much).

How can I make it faster?

```
def num_of_divisors(x):
    k=0
    b=x

    while x%2==0:
        x=x//2
        k=k+1
    z=1
    while x!=1:
        for y in range(3,b+1,2):
            a=0
            while x%y==0:
                x=x//y
                a=a+1
            z=z*(a+1)
    return(z*(k+1))

def triangular(n):
    return(n*(n+1)//2)

for n in range(1,10000):
    jk=triangular(n)
    if num_of_divisors(jk)>500:
        print(triangular(n))
        break
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most of the way there, so I'll give you a hint to avoid spoiling the problem:

- Your function `triangular` shows that you know that the formula for the \$ n \$th triangular number is $$ T(n) = { n(n+1) \over 2 }. $$ What numbers can possibly be divisors of \$ T(n) \$? Take a look at some small values of \$ n \$ and see if there is a pattern.

As far as code review goes, some quick points:

1. Better choice of variable names would make the code easier to read. For example `k` and `a` are essentially the same thing (each is the power of a prime in the factorization of `x`) so why do they have such different names?
2. `y` loops over the odd numbers, but if you're solving lots of Project Euler problems then you have probably written a prime number sieve and so you could use that here (and avoid the special case for 2 while you're about it).
3. Use *augmented assignment* to make the code shorter and simpler, for example, `z=z*(a+1)` can be written `z *= a + 1`.

Comment: Thanks , it now takes 10 seconds using standard python and half a second with pypy. Any other improvements in the num of divisors function?

Comment: About your second point: I thought looping over all odd numbers instead of prime numbers will be faster since prime numbers need not be generated . Is this not true?

Comment: Sieve for the prime numbers once and remember them.

Answer (score 4):

## Language

Your tag states Python3. Do note this will also work on Python2.

## Style

Your style is not according to Python standards. It would be much better to read if you adhered to the basics of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Also, your loop `n in range` starts at `1` now. What if you want to re-use this code and give invalid input?

Your code would hang if you accidentally started a `0`. This would allow `triangular(0`, resulting in `num_of_divisors(0)`. Such input would cause an infinite loop. It's good practice to prevent hangups (infinite loops) like these. The [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) statement is perfect to prevent a script from getting stuck in illegal states.

## Performance

The performance is awful. As you stated, `500` is too large for your script. Where `100` takes a couple of seconds, `200` takes over a minute.

According to benchmark(targeting `200`, `mean` in seconds):

```
           name | rank | runs |  mean |    sd | timesBaseline
----------------|------|------|-------|-------|--------------
num of divisors |    1 |   10 | 85.77 | 1.229 |           1.0
```

Again, awful. I estimate a run targeting `500` would take over a hundred hours.

The problem is your design isn't optimized, which is because the math behind this is slightly more complicated than you assume. Since [Gareth](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88707/52915) already answered that part, I see no point in repeating this. If learning by example is more your style, take a look at other entries for [Euler #12](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+euler+12) on Code Review.

Comment: Thank you for the review. How can I prevent the loop hangup problem?

Comment: Using [`assert`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/simple_stmts.html#assert) would be a good choice. They are meant for situations which should not happen.

Comment: @GarethRees I assume all code is written to last. After all, what's the point in reviewing if it isn't supposed to last? The code will hit an infinite loop at `n = 0`, so this situation should be asserted.