# Project Euler problem 12 Python

Tags: python, performance, beginner, mathematics, factors

I'm new to python and programming in general and I found Project Euler problems a good way to practice python. But my code is pretty slow. It seems to work, didn't wait long enough for the code to print the answer though. Any tips on how to make it faster ? I assume that you don't have to check **every single number** but that's just a guess any help appreciated.

```
tri_nums = [1]
divisors = []
temp_divisors =[]

while len(divisors) <= 500:
    for x in range(1, tri_nums[-1] + 1):
        if tri_nums[-1] % x == 0:
            temp_divisors.append(x)
    if len(temp_divisors) > len(divisors):
        divisors = temp_divisors[:]
    temp_divisors.clear()

    print("Number: " + str(tri_nums[-1]))
    print("Number of divisors: " + str(len(divisors)))
    print("List of divisors: " + str(divisors))
    tri_nums.append(len(tri_nums) + 1 + tri_nums[-1])
```

Comment: You only need to check for divisors up to the square root of the number

Comment: i see and then it gives me half of the divisors, could you explain a math behind this (i feel really stupid rn)

Comment: It´s half, but you can get its pairs doing n / that divisor. [Here is an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811151/why-do-we-check-up-to-the-square-root-of-a-prime-number-to-determine-if-it-is-pr)

Comment: "didn't wait long enough for the code to print the answer though." Why not? Don't you want to know whether it works for sure?

Comment: @Mast in this case, that would take hours if not days

Comment: @juvian Which means the solution is almost too awful to review. It *can* be done [much faster](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88707/52915).

Comment: Yes, its better to change algorithm rather than the code. Can still improve a lot just changing the code for the sqrt though

Comment: @mast i knew it was working cuz it's printing out the result every loop iteration

Comment: Project Euler soon requires way more maths than programming.  On a side note storing your results in lists also needs some memory and resources, expecially as you don't need them - using simple counters should give you another boost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid spoiling the problem for you, I'll offer some hints.

Hint 1:

> Have you read the Wikipedia article about the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)? It's always worth doing a bit of research into the mathematical background of a Project Euler problem.

Hint 2:

> There is a mathematical formula for the \$n\$th triangular number, namely \${1\over2}n(n+1)\$.

Hint 3:

> What do you know about the divisors of \${1\over2}n(n+1)\$? Try out some small examples and see if there is a pattern.

Hint 4:

> When a problem requires you to establish some facts about the divisors of all the numbers in a range, then what you need is a [*sieve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).